# How to execute the stored procedure from table using cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to execute a stored procedure from the table and if it ran successfully run the next procedure. There are 50 stored procedures in the table and some need to execute daily, some need to execute weekly and monthly.

I have done this but it is not working. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

```
DECLARE @ProcFreq int
DECLARE @ProcName varchar(100)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT ProcFreq, ProcName FROM @temp
OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ProcFreq, @ProcName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    EXEC @ProcName

    FETCH NExT FROM cur INTO @ProcFreq, @ProcName
END

CLOSE cur    
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Comment: Could you be a little more vague about "not working"? Do you want to execute stored procedure `mysp` with parameter value `@ProcName` while disregarding `@ProcFreq`?

Comment: What does mysp do? Can you show the code?

Comment: I am stuck on this code and I dont know how to do next step.

Comment: If the frequency says daily it will execute if it says monthly it will run every first of month or given date in column. If frequency says daily it will execute procedure and put the run time and date on next column.

Comment: @Justin I had an answer but your comment above totally threw off my post. You do not declare or define `@temp`? How can `@ProcFreq` be a string with 'daily', 'monthly' values if you declare it `int`? Overall, are you conditionally running 50 different stored procs iteratively or inside the stored proc, `mysp`?

Comment: @Parfait I want to run those procedure separately. I tried many ways and i couldnt find how to accomplish this task. how would you suggest to complete this task..

Comment: can you show the data in the proc table?

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @ProcFreq int
DECLARE @ProcName varchar(100),
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(100)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT ProcFreq, ProcName FROM @temp
OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ProcFreq, @ProcName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    SET @Sql = 'EXEC ' + @ProcName
    exec sp_executesql @Sql
    FETCH NExT FROM cur INTO @ProcFreq, @ProcName
END

CLOSE cur    
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Comment: dynamic sql is not necessary in this case, `exec @procname` is absolutely fine.